# How to add the expanded version of commands involving fzf to history?

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh, fzf

Say I would like to edit a file `./long/path/to/my/file/test.py` with Vim, but I do not remember the path to the file.

In this case, I would run `` vim `fzf` `` to use fuzzy search to find and edit the file.

What gets stored in my `~/.zsh_history` is `` vim `fzf` ``, which makes sense. I was wondering if it is possible to add an entry in the history that includes the expanded command, e.g., `vim ./long/path/to/my/file/test.py`. This would be useful not only for having a more accurate history but also in other programs like [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) and [McFly](https://github.com/cantino/mcfly).

Comment: Instead of running a command that calls `fzf`, bind a key to a widget that calls `fzf` and inserts the result. For example https://github.com/amaya382/zsh-fzf-widgets (no idea if it's good, it was just the top google hit for “zsh fzf widget”).